# How to listen on 192.168.1.1/subdir/ in node.js?

Tags: node.js, webserver, express

I'm using node.js with express and I would like to make it listen on "192.168.1.1/subdir/" instead of "192.168.1.1" how may I do without having to change all the url config in express?

Answer (score 2):

[express-namespace](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-namespace) can help you:

```
require('express-namespace')

app.namespace('/subdir', function(){
  app.get('/view', function(req, res){
    res.send('/subdir/view rendered');
  });

  app.get('/edit', function(req, res){
    res.send('/subdir/edit rendered');
  });

});
```